# iphone ios web browser that can open a pop up?

Tags: ios, xcode, popupwindow

I am trying to write a simple ios web browser app in xcode that can handle when accessing a website can open a popup window?

I can access a url in the xcode app, but can't get it handle a pop up window.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question so my answers will be based upon my understanding of what youre trying to accomplish.

Option 1: How about a little JQuery Mobile? see: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/pages/popup/

Option 2: Display a UIAlertView with a UIWebView as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

Add the UIWebViewDelegate in .h file and add the delegate methods of the webview

```
 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
 {
   //Add your code for popup window
 }
```